# How can I change this filed color originally?

Tags: webstorm

[image]

I wonder why Project window's color become yellow. And How can I fix this?

I guess it is changed while I set something about gitignore. Because before I touched git things, it's color wasn't yellow.

Please let me know how can I fix this :(

Answer (score 0):

please delete the .idea file and close and reopen the IDE it should be fixed